# display collection items - backbone

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I have a problem trying to display collection items, in particular I get an error on collection.each() function:

```
getTodo: function(){
  this.todos = new TodosCollection;
  this.todos.query = new Parse.Query("test");
  this.todos.fetch({
success:function(obj){
    console.log(obj.length);
    obj.each(this.addOne);
    }
  });
},
addOne: function(todo){
  console.log(todo);
}
```

with this code I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

console.log(obj.lenght) is != 0, so where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

The `this` from which you call the `addOne` method is the callback, not your object - and the callback's property `addOne` is `undefined`, so you're trying to call `undefined` as a function. You can bind the callback to the object scope this way:

```
success: _.bind(function(obj){
  obj.each(this.addOne);
}, this)
```

Comment: A similar problem will happen inside `addOne` unless that too has been bound somewhere, you can `obj.each(this.addOne, this)` to sort that one out.

Comment: Sure - I did not bind it as in the example there was no reference to `this`in `addOne`, but probably in the actual code there will be some.